# Prove that the golden ratio is irrational by contradiction

Tags: analysis, elementary-number-theory, golden-ratio

I am struggling to see where the contradiction lies in my proof. In a previous example, $1/\phi = \phi-1$ where $\phi$ is the golden ratio $\frac{\sqrt{5} + 1}{2}$.

Since I am proving by contradiction, I started out by assuming that $ϕ$ is rational. Then, by definition, there exists $a,b$ such that $\phi = a/b$. After some simple calculations and using the result shown from my previous example, I found that $\phi= b/(a-b)$. I also know that $b < a$ from directly calculating the ratio.

I know there is a contradiction in the result $ϕ = b/(a-b)$ but I cannot see it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You could start by proving that $\sqrt{5}$ is irrational, and then use the fact that sum and product of a nonzero rational and irrational number are irrational.

Comment: Another possible approach: $\phi$ is a root of $x^2 - x - 1$, but the only possible rational roots would be $\pm 1$, for example by using Gauss's lemma on factorization of polynomials in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ - and those obviously aren't roots.

Comment: If $b<a$, then $b/(a-b)$ is a fraction in lower terms, which contradicts the assumption that $a/b$ is in lowest terms. Thus, the golden ratio is irrational.

One corollary is that the square roots of 5 are irrational numbers, as $2-1=\sqrt{5}$

Answer (score 42):

Here's one idea that works directly without showing anything about $\sqrt 5$:

We know $\varphi > 1$ so if it is rational, we could write 
$$ \varphi = \frac{a}{b},$$
where $a > b > 0$ are integers and $\operatorname{gcd}(a,b) = 1$. Then using the relation $\frac{1}{\varphi} = \varphi - 1$ gives 
$$ \frac{b}{a} = \frac{a - b}{b},$$
which is a contradiction since $\operatorname{gcd}(a,b) = 1$ by construction and $a > b$ (it would be a further reduction of a fraction that we already chose to be completely reduced).

Comment: Excellent solution!

Comment: Because the GCD of the two denominators would have to be greater than 1 if both _a_ and _b_ were rational?

Comment: @CJDennis no, but because $\operatorname{gcd}(a,b) = \operatorname{gcd}(b-a,b)$ whence both fractions are in reduced form which is unique, i.e., $a=b$, contradiction.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance but I am struggling to see why this is a contradiction. We assumed $a\over b$ was fully reduced and then showed ${a-b}\over b$ was fully reduced... how is this a contradiction?

Comment: @Thomas: one can think of it like so - by assumption, a > b so let c = a - b. Then we have b / a = c / b. Now, since all are integers, and a > b, we should be able to reduce the fraction on the left side to obtain exactly the fraction on the right be cancelling some terms; that is: 

b = k*c and a = k*b. But by assumption gcd(a, b) is 1.

Comment: Oh I get it now, thank you @Nitin for your response!

Comment: The irrationality of the square roots of 5 are a direct corollary of this proof.

Answer (score 10):

HINT: $$\sqrt{5}=\frac{2a-b}{b}$$ is a contradiction, since the numbers $a,b$ are rational and $$\frac{2a-b}{b}$$ is also rational and $\sqrt{5}$ is irrational

Comment: This really helps! Thank you  very much

Comment: ok you are welcome

Answer (score 8):

If $\phi=\frac ab$ with $\gcd(a,b)=1$ then $\frac 1{\phi}=\phi-1\implies\frac ba=\frac ab-1\implies b^2=a^2-ab=a(a-b)$

This means $b\mid a(a-b)$ but since $\gcd(a,b)=1$ then $b\mid a-b\implies b\mid a$ which is a contradiction.

Comment: For the uninitiated, what is that vertical line that you use in your conclusion?

Comment: it means "divides"

Answer (score 4):

Though Nitin showed an excellent solution (much better than mine), I've already typed the routine solution approach. So I'm posting it anyway:

If it is rational, we can write it in the form of the fraction $m/n$ where $m$ and $n$ are integers and have no common factors – always, otherwise it is not rational.
So we have
$$\frac{\sqrt5+1}{2}=\frac{m}{n}$$
$$\sqrt5=\frac{2m}{n}-1$$
But $\frac{2m}{n}-1$ is rational because $\frac{m}{n}$ is rational.
Therefore $\sqrt5$ is rational. But it is not. We have a contradition, so the whole number must be irrational. q.e.d.

If you want to prove that $\sqrt5$ is irrational. Do the same: if it is rational, we can write it in the form of the fraction $m/n$ where $m$ and $n$ are integers and have no common factors (We can factor out any common factors). So we have
$$\sqrt5=\frac{m}{n}$$ 
$$5=\frac{m^2}{n^2}$$
$$5n^2=m^2$$
Therefore $m$ is divisible by $5$ and we can re-rewrite it as $m=5k$. So we have
$$5n^2=25k^2$$
$$n^2=5k^2$$
Therefore $n$ is also divisible by 5 and we can re-rewrite it as $n=5p$. Therefore, the fraction $\frac{m}{n}$ can be simplified because the numerator and denominator have a common factor of $5$, which contradicts our assumption that there will be no common factors. This cannot be, so $\sqrt5$ cannot be rational. Therefore it’s irrational. q.e.d.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose $\phi$ is rational.  From $\frac{1}{\phi} = \phi - 1$, we see that $\phi$ satisfies the polynomial $\phi^2 - \phi - 1 = 0$.  By the [rational root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem) , $\phi = p/q$ where $p | -1$ and $q | 1$, forcing $\phi = \pm 1$.  But neither of these is a root, contradicting that $\phi$ is rational.  Therefore, $\phi$ is not rational.

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

Let´s assume that φ is rational.

a/b=φ is completely reduced (we can do this when it is rational)

b<a (by definition)

a/b =  (1+ √5)/2  < ( 1 + √9) / 2 = 2   →   a < 2 b →  a-b < b

From  1/φ = φ - 1

→   b/a = a/b -1 = (a - b)/b

b/a is completely reduced but is equal to another fraction with both a smaller denominator and a smaller numerator.

This is a contradiction, so φ is not rational.

I explained a bit more in :
https://www.valgetal.com/physics/Mathematics/Golden%20Ratio/Golden%20Ratio.htm